# execute cron job every 2 hour with 30 min duration

Tags: php, cron

I have searched SO, but can't seem to find any topic covering my little problem.

I'm quite new to cron jobs.

I have an IP based alarm. This alarm can control wireless power outlets, turning them on and off within the web based control panel. I can control the power outlets with a simple http command, making them turn on and off.

I have made a php script taking care of this. Right now they are 2 separate scripts, one for turning on and one for turning off. The script are only controlling one specific power outlet.

My problem is that i need a time based switching scheme. First I thought of making the php script sleep, but at the sleep time is 1 hour, it would not be my first choice.

So here we go.

Is it possible to set up cron job to:

1: run the on script for 1 sec, just to trigger the http command in the script.
2: wait 1 hour.
3: run the off script for 1 sec to trigger the http command.
4: wait 2 hours.
5: start all over again.

There are no problem with the alarm system, sending the OFF http command even if the power outlet is off, and vice versa.

Comment: You could just call the same script each time and save the state of the alarm in-between so the script knows which part to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all commands into single and run it every 3 hours.

```
0   */3 *   *   *   /path/to/1st_script; sleep 3600; /path/to/2nd_script
```

This will run the 1st_script every 3 hours on 0-minute, then wait 1 hour, then run the 2nd_script.

Answer (score 0):

Now I just have to figure out how to make the system accept my php script in cronjob.

I have read that I have to add /usr/bin/php to the cronjob command, but that does not exist on my RaspberryPi server (nginx with FPM/FastCGI)